# Расширение на конце ссылки

Tags: ссылки

Здравствуйте! Хотела попробовать обменяться ссылками с сайтами родственной тематики и появился вопрос: почему в конце адреса страницы со ссылками не указывается расширение, вот пример: http://www.prazdnuem.ru/links/9/?page=1. Для чего так делается?

Comment: Потому что [ЧПУ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)) рулят. Хотя этот `?page=1`, конечно, не слишком красив

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При указании ссылки на сайт типо [www.site.ru](http://www.site.ru) сервер возвращает страницу по умолчанию, чаще всего это index.html, index.php. Можно сразу запросить эту страницу как [www.site.ru/index.html,](http://www.site.ru/index.html,) но такой адрес менее запоминаем. Для сайтов с динамическим содержимым для вывода любой страницы используется именно файл index.php который возвращается по умолчанию. Однако что бы дать серверу понять какую именно страницу нужно вывести используют запросы. Выглядят они так [www.site.ru/index.php?key=value.](http://www.site.ru/index.php?key=value.) Поскольку index.php выводится по умолчанию, его опускают, и получается [www.site.ru/?key=value.](http://www.site.ru/?key=value.)

Comment: А если у них там не похапе? `?page=1` - это всего-лишь GET-аргумент, передаваемый исполнителю, который может быть и не PHP-скриптом

Comment: Я просто постарался доступно пояснить суть. Вместо index.php может быть index.asp, index.aspx (Active Server Pages) или index.jsp (JavaServer Pages)

Comment: Ага, вы еще скажите `index.py` или `index.rb`

Answer (score 1):

возможно дело в modrewrite делают(делали)для SEO оптимизации и сокрытия реализаций.

Comment: А ссылки на таких страницах индексируютя?

Comment: @Регина 

Что вы, в самом деле. Полинтернета уже ЧПУ юзают и у всех все нормально

Comment: Спасибо, я в интернете недавно!